# Mock functional argument of the function

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, mockito, specs2

I'm developing web app using Scala, Play Framework. And I need to test  controller with the custom action. Please, take a look on the code:

```
package controllers.helpers

import play.api.mvc.{ActionBuilder, Request, Result}

import scala.concurrent.Future

class CustomAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
    // do some stuff
    block(request)
  }
}


package controllers

import javax.inject.Singleton

import play.api.mvc.Controller

@Singleton
class SomeController @Inject() (customAction: CustomAction
                           ) extends Controller {

  def foo() = customAction(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    // do some stuff and create result
  } 
}
```

And below you can find a code of the test class. I use Specs2 and I got `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException` on the line with `customeActionMock.invokeBlock(any[Request[_]], any[(Request[_]) => Future[Result]]) returns mock[Future[Result]]`

```
package controllers
import controllers.helpers.CustomAction
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import play.api.mvc.{Request, Result}
import play.api.test.{FakeHeaders, FakeRequest, PlaySpecification}

import scala.concurrent.Future

class SomeControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {
  private val customeActionMock = mock[CustomAction]
  customeActionMock.invokeBlock(any[Request[_]], any[(Request[_]) => Future[Result]]) returns mock[Future[Result]] //this doesn't work, exception is thrown there


  "SomController" should {
    "respond Ok on valid request" in {
      val result = new UserController(customeActionMock).foo()(FakeRequest())
      status(result) shouldEqual OK
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that I mock `block` parameter of the `CustomAction` incorrectly. Can someone help me to do it properly?

Comment: The way you setup your test, the value `result` would hold the mocked value `mock[Future[Result]]`. Put differently, if you mock the code that is supposed to run the `block`, the code inside your action won't be run.. I think I would not mock `CustomAction`, but make it part of the test.

Answer (score 1):

My project uses Play 2.5.x. I use scalatest. This is how I test controllers.

```
import org.scalatestplus.play.OneAppPerSuite
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.time.{Millis, Seconds, Span}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import scala.concurrent.Future

class SomeControllerSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with ScalaFutures with OneAppPerSuite {
private val customeActionMock = new CustomAction // create an instance of a class 
implicit val defaultPatience = PatienceConfig(timeout =  Span(5,Seconds), interval = Span(500, Millis))

it should "respond Ok on valid request" in {
  val resultF : Future[Result] = new UserController(customeActionMock).foo()(FakeRequest())
  whenReady(resultF) { resultR =>
        resultR.header.status shouldBe 200
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using 2.6 with play cache enabled. I spend 3 hours trying to mock that implementation. I ended up creating my own caching class for tests because I got the same error. Thumb down for Play2. Thanks @ecamur.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock the CustomAction :

```
class SomeControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {
  private val customeActionMock = new CustomAction


  "SomController" should {
    "respond Ok on valid request" in {
      val result = new UserController(customeActionMock).foo()(FakeRequest())
      status(result) shouldEqual OK
    }
  }
}
```